# How to change the file name to be downloaded

Tags: java, configuration, parameters, struts2, actionresult

Here is I have the result:

```xml
<result name="success" type="stream">
   <param name="contentDisposition">attachment;filename="${fileName}"</param>
</result>
```

How it works now: if my `fileName` is `raghu.txt` in DB it will be downloaded as `raghu.txt`.

What I want: regardless of `fileName` the output name should be `ravi.txt`.

Comment: either hard code file name in struts.xml or define global file name in your base action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try in your action

```
public String getFileName() {
  return "ravi.txt";
}
```

When result is executed it will get the dynamic parameter via this method, and it will return the value wanted. But, it's only to show you how dynamic parameters work, actually if the configuration used the dynamic parameter you should modify the action code and `setFileName("ravi.txt");` before the result code is returned. Then you can remain the normal getter.

Comment: Thank you! but is there is any way we can do it in struts.xml ?

Answer (score 2):

Replace `${fileName}` with a fixed string:

```
<result name="success" type="stream">
   <param name="contentDisposition">attachment;filename="ravi.txt"</param>
</result>
```